# PHP update of Query with Form

Tags: php, sql, forms, loops, post

Here is code I use to update data of one row of form table. This is the code I wanna change.
The change should allows me update not only one row of the shown table but every line:

```
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $UpraveneQuery = "UPDATE uctovnictvo SET meno='$_POST[meno]', datum='$_POST[datum]', obchod='$_POST[obchod]', druh='$_POST[druh]', cena='$_POST[cena]', Poznamka='$_POST[poznamka]' WHERE  uct_id='$_POST[hidden]' ";   //--------------
        mysql_query($UpraveneQuery, $con);
    };
```

here are data with which I work for this particular case:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uctovnictvo WHERE meno IN ('" . implode('\', \'', $option_meno) . "') AND obchod IN ('" . implode('\', \'', $option_obchod) . "') AND druh IN ('" . implode('\', \'', $option_druh) . "') AND  datum BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_end'  ORDER BY $order";                 
    $mojeData = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die($sql."<br/><br/> Chyba 1 je:".mysql_error());//run query a ulozit to premennej
```

here is code which generates form table which allows me to change content of it. Every row of the table has its own button for deleting or updating the row.
**NOW**
When I clik on **ulozit zmenu** (update) on certain row it allows me to post values of that one row and update variables of the row (query).
**PLAN**
I dont want to have button **ulozit zmenu** (update) next to every row of the table but only one butto which will post values of every **shown** row of the table.

```
    while($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array($mojeData))
    {
        echo "<form action=index-5.php method=post>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='meno[]' value='" . $zaznam['meno'] . "'>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=date name='datum[]' value='" . $zaznam['datum'] . "'>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='obchod[]' value='" . $zaznam['obchod'] . "'>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='druh[]' value='" . $zaznam['druh'] . "'>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input step=any type='number[]' name=cena value='" . $zaznam['cena'] . "'>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='poznamka[]' value='" . $zaznam['poznamka'] . "'>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name='update[]' value='ulozit zmenu'" . ">" . "</td>";[]
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name='zmazat[]' value='zmazat'" . ">" . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Please, at least, escape your values before creating your SQL sentence! With this code you're opening yourself to SQLInjection... Also, your question is that you would like to have 1 update button for all rows and when the button is pressed update all displayed rows?

Comment: U can tell me more about escape your values in message and yes u understand my question.